# How can I grab the element by matching text in its href attribute in BeautifulSoup

Tags: javascript, python, html, beautifulsoup

Website has several of the href tag, and I parsed it by the text.
For example,

```
<a href="#goUrl" onClick="javascript:goUrl('/board/list.do?boardID=1111&m=100&s=111', 'N')">test1</a>
<a href="#goUrl" onClick="javascript:goUrl('/board/list.do?boardID=1111&m=200&s=111', 'N')">test2</a>
<a href="#goUrl" onClick="javascript:goUrl('/board/list.do?boardID=1111&m=300&s=111', 'N')">test3</a>"
```

I used

```
bs = getBeautifulSoupRequests(board_url)
result = bs.findAll('a', href=True, text='test1')
```

and the result

```
"<a href="#goUrl" onClick="javascript:goUrl('/board/list.do?boardID=1111&m=100&s=111', 'N')">test1</a>
```

But I want to have result as follow

```
/board/list.do?boardID=1111&m=100&s=111
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You are pretty close. You just need to get the value of the `onclick` attribute and extract the link from there. You could use a regex pattern to match the link, or a quick and dirty `split()` as I show below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<a href="#goUrl" onClick="javascript:goUrl('/board/list.do?boardID=1111&m=100&s=111', 'N')">test1</a>
<a href="#goUrl" onClick="javascript:goUrl('/board/list.do?boardID=1111&m=200&s=111', 'N')">test2</a>
<a href="#goUrl" onClick="javascript:goUrl('/board/list.do?boardID=1111&m=300&s=111', 'N')">test3</a>"'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for t in soup.find_all('a', href=True, onclick=True, text='test1'):
    onclick = t['onclick'].split("'")[1]
    print(onclick)
```

**Output**

```
/board/list.do?boardID=1111&m=100&s=111
```

Comment: It was a big help. Thank you~